# How to load Class from another file - Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-studio-2013, classloader

I must use Visual Studio - in my university :< It's dumb program, I generate Class with in-build creator but studio throw me errors. I want to load Class to `main.cpp` from another file.

My `Node.h` file

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    virtual ~Node();
};
Define Node
```

And `Node.cpp` file

```
#include "Node.h"

Implementation of Node {

}

Node::Node(){
}


Node::~Node(){
}
```

Next we have errors:

> 1>  Node.cpp
>
> 1>c:\users\konrad\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\lists\lists\node.cpp(3): error C2146: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before identifier 'Node'
>
> 1>c:\users\konrad\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\lists\lists\node.cpp(3): error C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> 1>c:\users\konrad\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\lists\lists\node.cpp(3): error C2146: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before identifier 'of'
>
> 1>c:\users\konrad\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\lists\lists\node.cpp(3): error C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before '{'
>
> 1>c:\users\konrad\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\lists\lists\node.cpp(3): error C2447: '{' : missing
>   function header (old-style formal list?)

What I do wrong? And how after this load Node class to `main.cpp`? Dumb Visual.

Comment: What is `Implementation of Node` ? You don't need that. Just include the header and write definitions in the source file.

Comment: Visual Studio may or may not be "dumb", but that's a bit rich coming from someone who thinks `Implementation of` is c++

Comment: Visual generate mi this files when I do "Add -> Class..."

Comment: In *that* case I am speechless *i.e.* "dumb"

Comment: Better Visual Studio than Turbo C++. Why not just add files and manually type in the code?

Comment: @crashmstr I prefer assembly but my teacher prefer C++. I don't know why we can't write object programs in ASM16 :< (it's joke)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to edit your .h and .cpp to look like below:

My `Node.h` file

```
#pragma once
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    virtual ~Node();
};
```

And `Node.cpp` file

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(){
}


Node::~Node(){
}
```

Comment: I have been working on linux/mac/windows for 5 years now. I think Xcode is the best (forget the last couple of months' crashes and bugs), then Visual Studio, last one would be my favourite (vi and cmake)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is providing a *stencil* and some code so you don't have to type *as much*.  The code is not compilable and needs modification by you.

The "Implementation of Node" should be treated as a comment.

There are better code generating tools, search the internet.

Visual Studio can't write all the `Node` class because it can't read your mind.

At some point, you will have to type.

I highly recommend developing your own *stencils* so that you can use an editor and perform a "global replace".  Again, don't expect the replace to be 100% perfect; the objective is to save some typing time.

**Edit 1:**
Remember, Visual Studio created a file using a Microsoft coding style which may not agree to your style.

Comment: Thanks, I know how it works now. I'm newby and I start now with Studio :<